# Problem importing images from a CSV file - Magento ver. 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, csv, importexport

Magento ver. 1.9.2.2

I've been working on this issue for several days and have read numerous articles. I have uncovered a few clues but can't tell where the hang up is.

Here is a link to a test CSV file used for importing:
http://webventions.com/wilsonandson/test_import.csv

The file was based on an export from Magento.

The media images used on the product pages don't import.
The main, small, and thumbnail image all load and show on the front end. However, they do not show up on the back-end.

The media image files have been moved by the import tool from the "import" folder to the "catalog-product" folder, and the images "test2.png" and "test3.png" do show up in the `importexport_importdata` database table.

Below is an SQL snippet from the database dump:

```
"_media_attribute_id":"88","_media_image":"test2.png","_media_lable":null,"_media_position":null,"_media_is_disabled":null}
```

Media attribute id #88 is the id of the `media_gallery` attribute.
Also tried using the id for the `gallery` attribute with no success.
Does anyone have any advice for where to look?